# ggplot2: How to combine histogram, rug plot, and logistic regression prediction in a single graph

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, overlap, logistic-regression

I am trying to plot combined graphs for logistic regressions as the function [logi.hist.plot](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/popbio/docs/logi.hist.plot) but I would like to do it using [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/) (aesthetic reasons).

The problem is that only one of the histograms should have the scale_y_reverse().

Is there any way to specify this in a single plot (see code below) or to overlap the two histograms by using coordinates that can be passed to the previous plot?

```
ggplot(dat) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=ind, y=dep)) + 
    stat_smooth(aes(x=ind, y=dep), method=glm, method.args=list(family="binomial"), se=FALSE) + 
    geom_histogram(data=dat[dat$dep==0,], aes(x=ind)) +
    geom_histogram(data=dat[dat$dep==1,], aes(x=ind)) ## + scale_y_reverse()
```

This final plot is what I have been trying to achieve:

[image: derisable outcome]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We use `geom_segment` to create the "bars" for the histogram and also to create the rug plots. Adjust the `size` parameter to change the "bar" widths in the histogram. In the example below, the bar heights are equal to the percentage of values within a given x range. If you want to change the absolute heights of the bars, just multiply `n/sum(n)` by a scaling factor when you create the `h` data frame of histogram counts.

To generate histogram counts for the plot, we pre-summarize the data to create the histogram values. Note the `ifelse` statement in the `mutate` function, which adjusts the values of `pct` in order to get the upward and downward bars in the plot, depending on whether `y` is 0 or 1, respectively. You can do this in the plot code itself, but then you need two separate calls to `geom_segment`.

```
library(dplyr)

# Fake data
set.seed(1926)
dat = data.frame(y = sample(0:1, 1000, replace=TRUE))
dat$x1 = rnorm(1000, 5, 2) * (dat$y+1)

# Summarise data to create histogram counts
h = dat %>% group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(breaks = cut(x1, breaks=seq(-2,20,0.5), labels=seq(-1.75,20,0.5), 
                      include.lowest=TRUE),
         breaks = as.numeric(as.character(breaks))) %>%
  group_by(y, breaks) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(pct = ifelse(y==0, n/sum(n), 1 - n/sum(n))) 

ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data=h, size=4, show.legend=FALSE,
               aes(x=breaks, xend=breaks, y=y, yend=pct, colour=factor(y))) +
  geom_segment(dat=dat[dat$y==0,], aes(x=x1, xend=x1, y=0, yend=-0.02), size=0.2, colour="grey30") +
  geom_segment(dat=dat[dat$y==1,], aes(x=x1, xend=x1, y=1, yend=1.02), size=0.2, colour="grey30") +
  geom_line(data=data.frame(x=seq(-2,20,0.1), 
                            y=predict(glm(y ~ x1, family="binomial", data=dat), 
                                      newdata=data.frame(x1=seq(-2,20,0.1)),
                                      type="response")), 
            aes(x,y), colour="grey50", lwd=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.02,1.02)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1,20)) +
  theme_bw(base_size=12)
```

[image]

Comment: Can also swap out the second `geom_segment` for `geom_rug(dat=dat[dat$y==0,], sides = "b")`, and the third for `geom_rug(dat=dat[dat$y==1,], sides = "t")`