# Add inverted density plot in a logistic regression - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

I have the following case:

```
### GENERATING DATA

set.seed(123)

x1 = rnorm(1000)            
x2 = rnorm(1000)
z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2        
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))         
y = pr > 0.5               
y1 = ifelse(y == "TRUE", 1, 0)

ex = data.frame(y = y, y1 = y1, x1 = x1, x2 = x2)


### PLOTING THE BINOMIAL REGRESSION

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(ex, aes(x=x1, y=y1)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2, cex = 3) +
  stat_smooth(method="glm", se=T, method.args = list(family=binomial)) +
  geom_density(data = ex[!ex$y, ], aes(x = x1, y = ..density..),
               alpha = 0.2, fill = "tomato") +
  theme_bw()
```

This code gives me:

[image]

**I need to add an inverted density plot for upper points**, something like this (I've tried to use the code of image bellow, available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366499/ggplot2-how-to-combine-histogram-rug-plot-and-logistic-regression-prediction), but without success):

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: while this can be coded with native ggplot, you might find {ggExtra} helpful to add marginal plots: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggExtra/vignettes/ggExtra.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `geom_polygon` with `stat="density"` where we could invert the density using `after_stat(1 - density)`. Additionally I added a `geom_path` for the black colored outline (`geom_polygon` will connect the endpoints too):

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(ex, aes(x = x1, y = y1)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2, cex = 3) +
  stat_smooth(method = "glm", se = T, method.args = list(family = binomial)) +
  geom_density(
    data = ex[!ex$y, ], aes(x = x1, y = after_stat(density)),
    alpha = 0.2, fill = "tomato"
  ) +
  geom_polygon(
    data = ex[ex$y, ], aes(x = x1, y = after_stat(1 - density)),
    alpha = 0.2, fill = "blue", stat = "density"
  ) +
  geom_path(
    data = ex[ex$y, ], aes(x = x1, y = after_stat(1 - density)),
    stat = "density", color = "black"
  ) +
  theme_bw()
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]